# Android JNI call

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have tried writing a jni call for the simple c code. when i try to install this on the phone running 2.3.3 it doesnt install, sometimes even if it installs then it is being force closed.Please help me with this. the code details are as follows:

The java code of which i generate the header file.

```
package com.hosa;

public class edgejava
{
static{
    System.loadLibrary("edgejava");
}
public native int main();
```

}

the generated header file is as below

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_hosa_edgejava */

#ifndef _Included_com_hosa_edgejava
#define _Included_com_hosa_edgejava
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif
 /*
  * Class:     com_hosa_edgejava
  * Method:    main
  * Signature: ()I
  */
  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_hosa_edgejava_main
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
 #endif
```

the implementation of native function is as below

```
#include "com_hosa_edgejava.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_pes_edgejava_main(JNIEnv *, jobject){
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
    imshow("edges", edges);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
// the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
return 0;
```

}

the android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include /home/srijith/android-opencv/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := edgejava
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := edgecpp.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

the application.mk

```
 APP_MODULES      := edgejava
 APP_STL := gnustl_static
 APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
```

the activity file is as follows

```
package com.hosa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Andedge2Activity extends Activity {
edgejava nativelib;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    nativelib= new edgejava();
    int i=nativelib.main();
    System.out.println("value returned to andedgeactivity "+i);
}
```

}

All necessary changes to the manifest has been done like mention of use of camera and permissions has been set.

**Edit**:
I have changed the `com_pes_edgejava` to `com_hosa_edgejava_main` but still not working...

Any other solutions ??????

Comment: What does the Android Log say when your application is forced to close? Maybe some crash message to help debug the situation?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a forum; we expect answers to *actually answer the question*.  If you need to interact with other users, you can leave comments on their answers.  When you hit 50 rep, you will be able to leave comments everywhere.  If you need to add details, you can [edit] your question.  For all other matters, please see our [faq] or visit [meta], where we discuss StackOverflow.

Comment: @Gaurav:  Don't edit people's answers to add your questions.  Edit your original question or post a comment to their question.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in you *Packname* change your application package `com.hosa` to `com_pes_edgejava`.

In your JNI file you will see function(main) declaration like JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_pes_edgejava_main()

Java_`com_pes_edgejava`_main

That's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

hotveryspicy points out the obvious issue (ie that you have com_pes when you should have com_hosa).  As for the fact it doesn't work still, I would suspect this comes down to the "using namespace cv".  As a result you are declaring your JNI function inside the cv namespace which is not correct.  This is one of the reasons that the using keyword is something to be wary of.

whats wrong with just putting cv:: on front of the calls to functions and definitions of structs/classes that are in that namespace?  Its far better at self documenting that way anyway.